# Cant Get View bindings working when setting up RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have got the Recyclerview working with findViewById but cant get it working with View bindings.

This Works

```
val tdList: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.td_list);
tdList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
tdList.setHasFixedSize(true);
tdList.adapter = reportAdapter
```

But this does not work

```
tdBinding.tdList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
tdBinding.tdList.setHasFixedSize(true);
tdBinding.tdList.adapter = reportAdapter
```

onCreateViewHolder or onBindViewHolder are never called and I get an error 'No adapter attached; skipping layout' so no data is shown in the RecyclerView.

I've been trying to get this working for a few days with View Bindings and finally found the code to get it working with findViewById and part of me thinks I should just be glad I got it working but would like to understand why (also as findViewById is quite expensive).

The full code is

**DurationsReport.kt**

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.ActivityDurationsReportBinding
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.TaskDurationsBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

private const val TAG = "DurationsReportXX"

enum class SortColumns { NAME, DESCRIPTION, START_DATE, DURATION }

class DurationsReport : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val reportAdapter by lazy { DurationsRVAdapter(this, null) }
    var databaseCursor: Cursor? = null
    var sortOrder = SortColumns.NAME
    private val selection = "${DurationsContract.Columns.START_TIME} BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    private var selectionArgs = arrayOf("0", "1559347199")

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDurationsReportBinding
    private lateinit var tdBinding: TaskDurationsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val func = "onCreate"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityDurationsReportBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        tdBinding = TaskDurationsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        Log.d(TAG, "$func: Setup adapter")

        val tdList: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.td_list);
        tdList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        tdList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        tdList.adapter = reportAdapter

        // This does not work
        // tdBinding.tdList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        // tdBinding.tdList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // tdBinding.tdList.adapter = reportAdapter

        loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val func = "loadData"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        val order = when (sortOrder) {
            SortColumns.NAME -> DurationsContract.Columns.NAME
            SortColumns.DESCRIPTION -> DurationsContract.Columns.DESCRIPTION
            SortColumns.START_DATE -> DurationsContract.Columns.START_DATE
            SortColumns.DURATION -> DurationsContract.Columns.DURATION
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "order=$order")
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val cursor = application.contentResolver.query(
                DurationsContract.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, order
            )
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: cursor.count=${cursor?.count}")
            databaseCursor = cursor
            reportAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

**DurationsRVAdapter.kt**

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.TaskDurationItemsBinding
import java.util.Locale
import java.lang.IllegalStateException

private const val TAG = "DurationsRVAdapterXX"

class DurationsRVAdapter(context: Context, private var cursor: Cursor?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DurationsRVAdapter.DurationsViewHolder>() {

    inner class DurationsViewHolder(val bindings: TaskDurationItemsBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bindings.root)

    private val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(context)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DurationsViewHolder {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder")
        val view =
            TaskDurationItemsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return DurationsViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DurationsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val func = "onBindViewHolder"
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: position = $position")
        val cursor = cursor

        if (cursor != null && cursor.count != 0) {
            if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                throw IllegalStateException("Couldn't move cursor to position $position")
            }
            val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.NAME))
            val description =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.DESCRIPTION))
            val startTime =
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.START_TIME))
            val totalDuration =
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DurationsContract.Columns.DURATION))
            val userDate =
                dateFormat.format(startTime * 1000)  // The database stores seconds, we need milliseconds
            val totalTime = formatDuration(totalDuration)

            holder.bindings.tdName.text = name
            holder.bindings.tdDescription?.text = description
            holder.bindings.tdStart.text = userDate
            holder.bindings.tdDuration.text = totalTime
        }
    }

    private fun formatDuration(duration: Long): String {
        // convert duration Long to hours:mins:secs String (can be > 24 hours so cant use dateFormat)
        val hours = duration / 3600
        val remainder = duration - hours * 3600
        val minutes = remainder / 60
        val seconds = remainder % 60
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        val func = "getItemCount"
        val count = cursor?.count ?: 0
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: count=$count")
        return count
    }

    fun swapCursor(newCursor: Cursor?): Cursor? {
        val func = "swapCursor"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        if (newCursor === cursor) return null

        val numItems = itemCount
        val oldCursor = cursor

        cursor = newCursor
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: cursor.count=${cursor?.count}")

        Log.d(TAG, "$func newCursor.count=${newCursor?.count}, oldCursor.cont=${oldCursor?.count}")

        if (newCursor != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func notify the observers about the new cursor")
            // notify the observers about the new cursor
            this.notifyDataSetChanged()
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: notifyDataSetChanged")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func Notify observer about lack of dataset")
            // Notify observer about lack of dataset, all of it from 0 to newItems,
            // i.e. whole range of records has gone
            this.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, numItems)
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: notifyItemRangeChanged(0, $numItems)")
        }
        return oldCursor
    }

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        val func = "onAttachedToRecyclerView"
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: ${recyclerView.adapter.toString()}")
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        val func = "onDetachedFromRecyclerView"
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: ${recyclerView.adapter.toString()}")
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }
}
```

**task_durations.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_name_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_start_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_date"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_duration_heading"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_name_heading" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_duration_heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/td_text_duration"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_start_heading"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_start_heading" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/td_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/td_name_heading"
        tools:listitem="@layout/task_duration_items" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**task_duration_itesm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:showIn="@layout/task_durations">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        tools:text="@string/td_text_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_start"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/td_duration"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_name"
        tools:text="@string/td_text_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/td_duration"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/td_start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/td_start"
        tools:text="@string/td_text_duration" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use `binding.tdList` for `Recyclerview` because you are setting `setContentView(binding.root)` for Activity Layout instead of `tdBinding.root`

Answer (score 2):

If it works with `findViewById`, then your view is in your `binding` and not your `tdBinding`, because `findViewById` searches the layout that you set with `setContentView`.

If it didn't give a compiler error, you must have a view with the same ID in both layouts. I don't know why you have two layouts, since you're only using one of them.

View Binding is not better performing than `findViewById` unless you're using `findViewById` repeatedly to find the same view. I'm pretty sure View Binding uses `findViewById` internally. The purpose of View Binding is not better performance. It's for eliminating the need to manually sync up your code with your XML and risking runtime errors instead of compile-time errors.

Comment: Guess as ime only using one view from the layout there's no performance benefit if I was using several it only has to do one pass so from what I read there can be performance gains. The code above that works only uses one view binding but the version that doesn't work uses both. The two of yous don't have the same ID. Very sure Android studio gives an error if they do. The point is is the code that doesn't work doesn't give an error it just returns no records in recyclerview.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're saying in your comment. But anyway, in your posted code above that you said works, you never do anything with `tdBinding`, so that view is not part of your Activity's view hierarchy. Therefore `findViewById` is not searching its views. It only searches whatever was set with `setContentView`. You didn't post the XML code that goes with `ActivityDurationsReportBinding`, which is the binding you are currently searching with `findViewById` in your working code.

Comment: My guess is that you have created two alternate layouts for your activity, one named `activity_durations_report.xml` and one named `task_durations.xml`, and both of them have a RecyclerView with ID `td_list` in them. You're getting these two XML files and their associated bindings mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I did a search for @+id/td_list and the only place it was was task_durations.xml (there is a layout and land-layout).  You are correct about the layouts.  I've now committed everything.

Comment: Code at https://github.com/funkytwig/tasktimer/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/funkytwig/tasktimer and layouts at https://github.com/funkytwig/tasktimer/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/funkytwig/tasktimer & https://github.com/funkytwig/tasktimer/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/funkytwig/tasktimer.  I commented out the stuff that used the second view binding.  however i think as it's just one viewit'ss probably best to do it with findViewById.  Still, curios how to do it with view mindings but probably not worth the errort.

Comment: OK, I worked it out (see below).  The trick seems not to use multiple view bindings.  findViewById does work but I prefer the below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer was to just use one View Binding.  The master XML layout has the other layout as an include.  The trick is to give the include an ID then you can traverse the XML from both layouts in a single view binding.

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/items"
    layout="@layout/task_durations" />
```

The Kotlin code to to setup RecyclerView is

```
    binding.items.tdList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.items.tdList.setHasFixedSize(true)
    binding.items.tdList.adapter = reportAdapter
```

I think you generaly only need a single View Binding where you are using include, but as I said to traverse them you need to give the include a ID.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know you had one layout inside the other one somehow.

Comment: Yes, always tricky to know how much detail to include, and its not until you get the answer that you know how much was needed;).